# Why is $f\in C_{\infty}=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R})\mid \lim_{R\to\infty} \sup_{∣∣x∣∣>R} ∣f(x)∣=0\}$

Tags: mathematical-physics

Today in my mathematical quantum theory lecture our professor told us without any explanation, that if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ it follows that $f\in C_{\infty}=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R})\mid \lim_{R\to\infty} \sup_{∣∣x∣∣>R} ∣f(x)∣=0\}$, where we consider $R$ as a radius.

Is there an easy way to see that? For me it is not quite obvious. What informations do I get from the conditions that tell me, that this kind of functions are vanishing at infinity?

Comment: Perhaps math.stackexchange.com would be a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: Hi karla.tr. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: okay, thank you!

Comment: @karla.tr the proof I sketched below the previous post works also for the precise definition of $C_\infty$ given above.